# How to save the time taken using laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, laravel-5

Im confused, how can I save the time that spent in laravel 5? Please see my `html` and `js` code below:

```js
 var quiz_timer = $('.quiz-timer').html();
 var exact_time = parseInt($('.timer-value').html() - 1);
 var befores = 60;
 var setters = setInterval(function(){
  var zero_check = (exact_time == 0) ? '0' : '';
  var zero_check_sec = (befores < 10) ? '0' : '';
  var new_seconds = $('.quiz-timer').html(zero_check + exact_time.toString() + ':'+ zero_check_sec + --befores);

  if(exact_time == 00 && befores == 00){
   clearInterval(setters);
   alert('Time is up!');
  }

  if(befores == 0){
   exact_time--;
   befores = 60;
  }

 }, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="quiz-timer">
  <span class="timer-value">2</span>:00
</span>
```

Comment: Do you know what a GET param is?

Comment: Nope, whats that for?

Comment: Sending information to the server. The idea is to open a URL like `/index.php?action=savetime&time=504` to store the value 504 on the server. The above URL has two params, `action` and `time`. If you don't know about this, it is *WAY* too early to be asking questions on here.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I know this thing, I just don't know how to call it.

Comment: Ok, you can either simply open a new page, like `window.location = "/index.php?...";` or run an AJAX request to send the data in the background.